# Play 180 degree videos on samsung gear vr

Tags: virtual-reality, samsung-galaxy-gear, gear-vr

I am starting a new business which will allow users to download videos and watch them through the Samsung Gear VR.

My videos are 3d 180 degrees using the Gopro Hero3+ duel system.

Now I can get my video to play as a 360 by naming is filename_360.mp4

The gearVR recognises this and makes it stretch to 360, however I cannot get it to work and only show 180 degrees.

I have downloaded a video from another website which has 180 degrees vision, and when you look around you can see 180 degrees pitch black. So somehow they have managed to trick the gearvr into it being 360, but with only 180 degree of content present.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this ?

Comment: What if you add "180x180_3dh" to the filename? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144210/playing-stereoscopic-3d-video-on-gearvr-headset?rq=1

Comment: Just out of curiousity, which of the suggestions did you go for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another thread on the subject: https://forums.oculus.com/community/discussion/23890/how-to-play-180-3d-video

If changing the name of the video doesn't work, there is of course the 'ugly' solution of adding enough padding around your video so that it appears 180 even though it's 360.

Comment: Hello reden, how do you put more padding around your video?

Comment: The idea was to do it in a video editing program. This is why it's the 'ugly' solution, since it would add to the size of the file. If you open the downloaded video in a normal video player you should be able to see if this is the case. If the shot material appears to fill the entire player however, there must be a better solution.

Comment: ive decided im just going to do 360 degree videos now to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

Just download moon vr player app from oculus. Its the only app i found that supports 180 videos. And have an interesting future...the "air view" that gives you the option to just download videos on your PC and watch them through VR with wifi instead of copping on you phone. Hope that works for you

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy. It's not the name of the file, but the name of the folder. In new gear vr app v.1.065, you can just simply put the file into a folder name 360videos and it's done.  But I not recommend it, because it just dtretch 180 degree video into 360 pano mode making eveyone looks ugly wide and fat. Are you sure you eant this? Hahaha!